# The most convenient way for separating wifi and LAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, administration

If there is a company want to have two networks for the user

1. LAN which is very restricted ( proxy and whitelisting of hostnames and connected to servers)
2. WIFI that is used for free accessing to any site ( Isolated from Network and servers)

The employee is using a laptop for both usage ( WIFI and LAN)

What is the most convenient way for normal user for switching between two networks without adding extra cost and without having two networks accessible in same time

Comment: Are you asking how to disable quickly a network adapter?

Comment: Yes for normal user

Comment: Computers come today without Ethernet (I am working on one as we speak here). There need the same resources as Ethernet users. So we do not bother separating along lines of wired / wireless; rather just provide limited wireless guest access.

Comment: Don't forget that people are using the computers and will use the easiest possible approach including using VPN to access company resources. After years of helping businesses, people respond responsibly.

Comment: From security perspective ,we want to have two networks ( WIFI which is separated from the network ) and LAN which is used for Servers access. and we don't want the employee to use both in the same time but be able to switch easily

Comment: @harrymc, yes disable and enable but for a user with no tech skills

Comment: Create `.bat` files with the commands from my link.

Comment: @harrymc thanks!